# SharePoint Designer cannot be disable for Administrator Account

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-designer

The problem is that when I disable the "SharePoint Designer" from the "SharePoint Designer Settings" (Site Collection Level), I can still edit this with my Administrator account. It works fine for another users who is not the Administrator. Do this behavior is know in SharePoint? Can someone explain me why this happen? If not, how can I disable the "Edit with SharePoint designer" for the Admin. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To disable SharePoint Designer for even Site Collection admins, you need to do so at the web application level via SharePoint Central Admin.

The setting you're changing at the Site Collection level only affects Site Owners & Designers; it does not, as you've seen, have any affect on Site Collection admins.

For instructions on disabling SharePoint Designer for an entire web app via SP Central Admin, see this guide here:
http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint-designer-help/managing-sharepoint-designer-2010-HA101838275.aspx#_Toc257189517